# After processing switch cases, C doesn't read the system() function

Tags: c, switch-statement, pyautogui

*Beginner Alert*

I was trying something in `C` that uses 3 functions and `system()` function. It also includes a `Python` file that simulates (alt+tab) with pyautogui. The problem is that
it somehow passes the `system("clear")` command after finishing `switch` statement.

Here's the `C` Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int makeSwitch() {

  int x;
  printf("\nType and enter one of them:");
  printf("\n\n(1) - (2)");
  printf("\n\n> ");
  scanf("%d", & x);

  int y;
  switch (x) {

  case 1:
    printf("I like 1");
    y = 1;
    break;
  case 2:
    y = 2;
    printf("I like 2");
    break;

  default:
    system("python3 tb.py");
    y = 3;
    break;
  }

  system("clear");

  return y;
}
void makePrint(int b) {
  system("clear");

  if (b == 1) {
    printf("I like one\n");
  } else if (b == 2) {
    printf("I like two\n");
  } else if (b == 3) {
    printf("Hotkey: alt + tab\n");
  } else {
    printf("Command not found\n");
  }

}
int main() {

  int x = makeSwitch();
  makePrint(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the `Python` code:

```
pyautogui.hotkey("alt","tab")
```

Output (1):

```
I like 1I like one
```

Output (2):

```
I like 2I like two
```

Output (y != 1 || y != 2):

```
Hotkey: alt + tab
```

So after `default:` the `system("clear")` works! I am wondering why.

My guess is I have to flush something that is keeping space and preventing the `system()` function to run.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You ignore the return value of `scanf()` at your own peril. It would allow you to verify that you successfully read something in. Otherwise you might use old or even non-initialised values. To make that visible, introduce another case 4 and init `x` to 4.

Comment: Unlike the other cases, your default case does not print anything to stdout, as far as I can tell.  If it did, I think you would find that the disposition and persistence on the screen of that output would be the same as that of the output printed by the other two cases.

Comment: If indeed that output is persisting on the screen then I agree that something a little strange seems to be going on, but I I'm not prepared to accept that it has anything to do with the `switch` statement.